# Incidence Rate Ratio Equal to One

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, generalized-linear-model

I am a student and I have a statistics question. I ran a generalized linear model  using  quasipossion as the distribution family ( y variable was continuous). The result I obtained for  one of my variables ,the three way interaction term, was significant p = 0.02 but the incidence rate ratio was equal to 1. I think this means that even though the p-value is significant, the incidence rate ratio being equal to 1 basically discredits the model ( in terms of this term) , as it doesn't show any decrease or increase in risk. Is this a correct interpretation? Thanks.

Comment: Could you tell us as explicitly as you can what you mean by the "incidence rate ratio" in this context?  Perhaps the output of a simple example of this analysis would help clear things up.

Comment: Sure,  the regression is investigating how the interation terms ( a biomarker, fasting and gender) influences a systemic inflammatory biomarker(y) . I am basically looking to see if these interactions can lower the inflammatory marker.  When I went to plot the data using https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/plot_model_estimates.html, function plot_model, it gave me the incidence rate ratio as a default.  But now reading more about it, I am not sure if that was appropriate given this is cross-sectional data. But I guess the incidence rate

Comment: would be relative risk.  The incidence rate among those with a high inflammatory marker , divided by those with a lower.  I saw that th the exponents of coefficients are equal to the incidence rate ratio (relative risk) in a Poisson Regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interactions in non-linear models are tricky. I would argue that the exponentiated interaction coefficient is not informative and does not "discredit" the model.

Here's the intuition for a two-way interaction that you can adopt to the three-way case. Your QP model for the expected value of $y$ conditional on $x$ and $z$ is
$$E[y \vert x,z] = \exp\{\alpha + \beta \cdot x + \gamma \cdot z + \delta \cdot x \cdot z\}.$$

Now suppose $x$ increased by one. The ratio of the new to old expected values is

$$\frac{E[y \vert x+1,z]}{E[y \vert x,z]} = \frac{\exp\{\alpha + \beta \cdot (x+1) + \gamma \cdot z + \delta \cdot (x+1) \cdot z\}}{\exp\{\alpha + \beta \cdot x + \gamma \cdot z + \delta \cdot x \cdot z\}}= \exp\{\beta\} \cdot \exp\{\delta \cdot z\}.$$

So the fact that $\exp\{\delta\} = 1$ is not very informative about how $z$ modifies the effect of $x$ on $y$ since the answer depends on the value of $z$. So if $\delta = 0.005$, then $\exp \{.005\} \approx 1$, but if $z$ is large enough, the $\exp\{.005 \cdot z\}$ term will still be greater than one.

I personally find it easier to think about $\delta$ in terms of changing the relationship of $y$ and $x$. This means looking at the un-exponentiated coefficient. Differentiating the expected value of $y$ with respect to $x$, we get

$$\frac{ \partial E[y \vert x,z]}{\partial x} = \exp \{\alpha + \beta \cdot x + \gamma \cdot z + \delta \cdot x \cdot z\} \cdot (\beta+ \delta \cdot z)=E[y \vert x,z]\cdot (\beta+ \delta \cdot z).$$

This uses the chain rule and the fact that $\frac{\partial\exp \{x\}}{\partial x} = \exp \{x\}$.

We can re-write the derivative as

$$\frac{ \partial E[y \vert x,z]}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{1}{E[y \vert x,z]}= \beta+ \delta \cdot z.$$

This is a semi-elasticity, which tells us the change in $y$ (in percent) from a one-unit change in $x$. People often multiply by 100 here. Note that it is a function of $z$.

We can then ask how that semi-elasticity itself depends on $z$, so we take the derivative with respect to $z$ this time to get $\delta$ all alone.

So if $\delta$ is 0.005, I would interpret that as a one-unit increase in $z$ is associated with a $100 \cdot 0.005 = 1/2\%$ bigger change in $y$ from a one-unit change $x$.

Comment: Thank you for your explaination. It makes more sense now.

Comment: @LittleBlueHeron There is no need to thank me. You can just select this as the answer if it cleared things up for you. You can always change your mind later if a better answer comes along.